# Unable to import library project as a module in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-studio, android-library

I'm trying to import the [JazzyViewPager](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/JazzyViewPager) library as a module in Android Studio in order to use it as a module dependency in my project. But I'm getting a strange error. When I try to import the library to Android Studio, it shows:

[image: unable to import project]

However, I've Android Support Repository installed and updated to the latest version, as you can see here:

[image]

Comment: What version of Android Studio are you running?

Comment: @Scott It's version 0.5.8

Answer (score 1):

You're hitting bug https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=68834 which causes Android Studio to not recognize the installed Support Repository in some cases. This is fixed in 0.5.9.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll update Android Studio and re-import the library.